# How to list items in directory in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

I'm currently working on an application that should be able to list out the items in a directory, however, after looking at the OS module in Nim, I couldn't find a way to see what is inside a directory. Is it possible that it hasn't been implemented yet, or did I maybe just look at the wrong place to find such a function?

So in short, how can I see what is inside /home/username/Documents/? How can I list out its content in Nim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to look in the [Iterators](https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#15) section of the `os` module.

There is [`walkDir`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#walkDir.i,string) and related iterators for this purpose:

> ```
> iterator walkDir(dir: string; relative = false; checkDir = false): tuple[
>     kind: PathComponent, path: string]
> ```
>
> Walks over the directory `dir` and yields for each directory or file in
> `dir`. The component type and full path for each item are returned.

You can use it like this:

```
import os

for kind, path in walkDir("/home/username/Documents/"):
  case kind:
  of pcFile:
    echo "File: ", path
  of pcDir:
    echo "Dir: ", path
  of pcLinkToFile:
    echo "Link to file: ", path
  of pcLinkToDir:
    echo "Link to dir: ", path
```

Answer (score -1):

Recursive traversal of subfolders with filtering by extensions:

```
import os
import sequtils

let
    targetFolder = "/home/user/media/"
    targetExt = @[".mp3", ".webm", ".mkv"]

proc scanFolder (tgPath: string, extLst: seq[string]): seq[string] =
    var
        fileNames: seq[string]
        path, name, ext: string
        
    for kind, obj in walkDir tgPath:
    
        if $kind == "pcDir" :
            fileNames = concat(fileNames, scanFolder(obj, extLst))

        (path, name, ext) = splitFile(obj)

        if ext in extLst:
            fileNames.add(obj)

    return fileNames 
            

var fileList = scanFolder(targetFolder, targetExt)   

for f in fileList:
    echo f
```

Comment: For recursive traversal there also is `walkDirRec`.